# Segregation of duties into Magento

Tags: magento

Is it possible to have a Segregation Of Duties (SOD) in magento? For example an user can only search product and put them into the cart while another can only approve the order and proceed to the payment process.

Comment: This is not integrated in Magento. Are you looking for a finished module or are you trying to implement this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

One "build-in" approach would be to let the first users search and order but place the orders in a to-be-reviewd-status. For the second user a backend user which is limited to approve orders could be created. But then your customers would have access to parts of your backend.

In an own module, you could make this approving available on the frontend.

Comment: I'm looking (if it exists) for a finished module.

My idea is a "super" customer can create other kind of "segregated custumers" related to his ID into magento in another table (i.e. SOD_Table). 

"Super" customer, using that table, can add some authorization objects. When a "segregated customer" navigate into the site, for magento is like he is a normal user with the ID of the "super customer" and in some page I can made a query to the SOD_Table to check if the user can see or not the page.

I'm not sure if my idea is the perfect solution...

Comment: This is a programmers FAQ so searching for Magento module would be off-topic.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Can you kindly tell me where to search? Google seem not help me...